# Cannot connect observable collection to collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Trying to make an income/month calculator. C# part is done, now I gotta make a collection view that updates automatically according to the number of months (1 month - 1 row / 5 months - 5 rows).

When I input values in the entry, and press the `Calculate` button, nothing really happens. No errors too.

**Collection View Code (XAML)**

```
          <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyIncomeCalculus}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="Month"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="Income with Rate"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Text="{Binding Month}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="{Binding Income}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

**Observable Collection + "Calculator" (C#)**

```
public partial class HomePage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };

    }
    public class MonthlyIncome
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public double Income { get; set; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome> MonthlyIncomeCalculus { get; set; } = new();
    private void Calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext = MonthlyIncomeCalculus;
        MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Clear();

        MonthlyIncome monthi;
        int Months = int.Parse(MonthInput.Text);
        int Income = int.Parse(IncomeInput.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
        {
            monthi = new MonthlyIncome();
            monthi.Month = i + 1;
            monthi.Income = (Income * Months) * 1.10;
            MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Add(monthi);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do **not** create a new instance of the collection every time you calculate.  Do it **once** at the beginning and if you need to reset call it’s Clear() method

Comment: A button that would clear the table sounds like something do-able and that can do the job... Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: just call `Clear()` instead of `new ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome>();` in `Calculate`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately, nothing happens when I press the Calculate button. No collection appears, not even errors... Kinda lost right now.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Calculate` method is running and populating your collection?  Are you sure the databinding of `MonthlyIncomeCalculus` is working correctly?

Comment: It is the databinding of MonthlyIncomeCalculus that is not working... For some reason, it says "No data context found for Binding"...

Comment: DataCintext is only used by Intellisense it has no impact on your code at runtime.  Without seeing more code I can’t help you.  Where do you assign the BindingContext for your page?

Comment: `Binding Context = MonthlyIncomeCalculus;` HomePage.xaml.cs. Either way, just edited the post so that you can see the current state of the code.

Comment: Then your ItemsSource should be “{Binding .}”

Comment: It worked! At last! But why a . and not MonthlyIncomeCalculus??

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyIncomeCalculus}"
```

It is telling it to look for a property with that name on your BindingContext

But since that property **is** your BindingContext, you need to use the entire BindingContext as the ItemsSource

```
ItemsSource=“{Binding .}”
```

Alternatively, you could have set the BindingContext this way

```
BindingContext = this;
```